# Fish Animation on barlasapaydin.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi there i am trying yo create fish animation which is on barlasapaydin.com that site but didn't get success creating that animation help me creating that animation and please provide code for that and i tried through html5 and css3 but no sccess

> ```
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="header">
>   <div class="loop">
>
>   </div>
>
>   </div>
>
>   <a href="#" class="logo">
>   <img src="logotype.png"/>
>   <span class="img-anim"></span>
>   <span class="img-anim1"></span>
>   <span class="img-anim2"></span>
>   <span class="img-anim3"></span>
>   <span class="img-anim4"></span>
>
>   </a>
>
> </div>
>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   $(document).ready(function(){
>       $("#header .loop").animate({background-position: '-2877px 0px';});
>
>
>
> });
> </script>
> ```

```
#header .loop{ border: 1px solid black; background: url(loop.png); width: 411px; height: 613px; position: absolute; left: 400px;
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 -moz-animation: loop ease-out 3000ms infinite; }
 @-moz-keyframes loop{ 0%{background: url(loop.png);
 background-position: 0px 0px;} 1%{background: url(loop.png);
 background-position: -411px 0;}
```

thank you

Comment: so have a timeout/interval and change the image source or toggle the element visibility that has the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've build that animation with combining `Adobe Flash`, `jQuery` and `JSON`.

First of all you need to create timeline animation with Flash without using `actionscript`.

Right click to your animation and select `Generate Sprite Sheet`.

Than define your desired options on opened screen and select `Data format` as `JSON`.

This step should give you `png` of sprite animation and `JSON` files like these:

- http://www.barlasapaydin.com/seq/loop.png
- http://www.barlasapaydin.com/seq/loop.json

**Here is a tutorial for this step:** http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/using-sprite-sheet-generator.html

Afterwards place your image to `html`. Define sizes and sprite position from `css`.

Play the loop animation with `jQuery`:

```
var loopTimer = null;
var lArr = [];
var curL;
var fps = 1000 / 30;
$.getJSON('seq/loop.json',function(data) {
  $.each(data.frames,function(key,val){
    lArr.push(this);
  });
});

curL = 0;
function startLoop() {
    loopAni();
}

function loopAni() {
  curL = (++curL) % lArr.length;
  loopTimer = setTimeout(loopAni, fps);
  var f = lArr[curL].frame;
  $('#loop')[0].style.backgroundPosition = '-'+ f.x +'px -'+ f.y +'px';
}

function pauseLoop() {
    clearTimeout(loopTimer);
}
```

Also you can inspect nonminifed javascript from this link: http://www.barlasapaydin.com/js/sss.js

Answer (score 1):

[here is good tutorial](http://24ways.org/2012/flashless-animation/) for this.

it is a simple sprite usage only important thing the div (your stage) must have exactly same height width with image part. for the animation trigger. for the animation use full size of he image.

if you are looking for a js fallback you might want to look [this examples](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/)

hope this helps.

Comment: Nice way to build sprite animation with css +1!

Answer (score 0):

You can use animated gif files for the animation. They are big, but uses less cpu power then some javasccript.

They are easily done. You can use gimp which is free. You can just make 5 Layers, name they like in this tutorial, export it to gif and you are done.

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/

If you use windows there is an gif animator tool from microsoft, which is more easy to use but less powerful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_GIF_Animator

Comment: thank you for the reply but i want to learn that code which they did on there website barlasapaydin.com.